# Multiple Iteration with System.in.read()

Tags: java, io

I am learning some basic IO right now and I decided to play around with some code, I wrote the following:

```
    do{ 
        System.out.print("Enter a char: ");
        char x = (char)System.in.read();
        
        
        if(x == 'q'){
            break;
        }
        
    }while(true);
```

When I run this code and provide an incorrect input (ie anything that's not 'q') I get multiple prompts instead of 1.

Enter a char: s

Enter a char: Enter a char: Enter a char:

The same does not occur when using the Scanner object to read data.
Why is this occurring?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you enter `s` followed by enter?

Comment: @JoachimSauer You are correct. I apologize. I AM trying to be helpful, but it's hot and humid in NYC, and that's put me in a mood. Again, let me apologize to your Mohammad Rizwaan. I need to take a break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char x = (char)System.in.read();` This line reads your inputs char by char. When you enter one char `s` and then press enter, actually you have two chars as follows;

1. s
2. \n (new line char, because you press enter)

Let's say you enter `ab` and then press enter, it means that you have 3 chars;

1. a
2. b
3. \n

So your code reads your input char by char on each iteration, and on each iteration you print `Enter a char:`.

But as you said that Scanner works just fine with same input. Because when you read input with `Scanner.nextLine()` you read your whole input as one string.

If you mark your code (inside loop) with breakpoint and debug it, you will see its behavior.